# What is the natural coaction $\delta: V \to V \otimes V^* \otimes V$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space. A professor said that there is a natural coaction $\delta: V \to V \otimes V^* \otimes V$. What is this natural coaction? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $V$ finite-dimensional?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi, yes, $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Well isn't that a huge hint...? Finite dimension is essential here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural counit $K\to {\rm End}(V)$ defined by $\lambda\mapsto\lambda\cdot{\rm Id}$.

There is a natural isomorphism $V\otimes V^*\xrightarrow{\sim}{\rm End}(V)$ defined by $v\otimes w\mapsto w(\cdot)v$.

Mix these ingredients to get a map $K\otimes V\to (V\otimes V^*)\otimes V$. Check it's a coaction.

There is also a natural isomorphism $K\otimes V\xrightarrow{\sim}V$ defined by $\lambda\otimes v\mapsto \lambda v$.

Comment: thank you very much. But there is a problem. I need to write down the map $V \to V \otimes V^* \otimes V$. Now we have $V \to K \otimes V \to End(V) \otimes V \to V \otimes V^* \otimes V$. But it seems that the map $V \to K \otimes V$ is not unique.

Comment: @LJR I don't see how nonuniqueness would be an issue. The map $v\mapsto 1\otimes v$ is natural.

Comment: thank you very much. I think that the composition $\delta$ of the maps $V \to K \otimes V \to End(V) \otimes V \to V \otimes V^* \otimes V$ is given by $v \mapsto \sum_i e_i \otimes e_i^* \otimes v$. We have $(1 \otimes \delta) \delta(v) = (\sum_i e_i \otimes e_i^*) \otimes  (\sum_j e_j \otimes e_j^*) \otimes v$. But it seems that $\Delta(\sum_i e_i \otimes e_i^*) \neq (\sum_i e_i \otimes e_i^*) \otimes (\sum_j e_j \otimes e_j^*)$. The coassociativity condition is not satisfied?

Comment: @LJR I never checked a coassociativity condition. I suppose we should do that though. What exactly is the comultiplication on ${\rm End}(V)$? (Also, please do not click the green check marks for an answer until you are satisfied with that answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see the coaction, which uses the natural isomorphisms $V\otimes V^*\cong\mathrm{End}(V)$ and $V^{**}\cong V$ ($V$ finite dimensional) is to dualize the (right) action of $\mathrm{End}(V^*)$ on $V^*$. That is, given the multiplication map
$$
m:V^*\otimes\mathrm{End}(V^*)\longrightarrow V^*,
$$
one has
$$
\delta=m^*:V\cong V^{**}\longrightarrow(V^*\otimes\mathrm{End}(V^*))^*\cong V\otimes V^*\otimes V
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be a basis of $V$. The natural coaction $\delta: V \to V \otimes V^* \otimes V$ is given by the following formula
$$
e_i \mapsto \sum_j e_i \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j. 
$$
Let $c_{ij} = e_i \otimes e_j^*$. The comultiplication on $V \otimes V^*$ is given by 
$$
\Delta(c_{ij}) = \sum_k c_{ik} \otimes c_{kj} = \sum_k e_i \otimes e_k^* \otimes e_k \otimes e_j^*.
$$
We have 
\begin{align}
(1 \otimes \delta) \delta(e_i) & = (1 \otimes \delta) (\sum_j e_i \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j) \\
& = \sum_{j} \sum_{k} e_i \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j \otimes e_k^* \otimes e_k \\
& = \sum_{k} \sum_{j} e_i \otimes e_k^* \otimes e_k \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j.
\end{align}
Here $1$ is the identity map on $V \otimes V^*$.
\begin{align}
(\Delta \otimes 1) \delta(e_i) & = (\Delta \otimes 1) (\sum_j e_i \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j) \\
& = \sum_{j} \sum_{k} e_i \otimes e_k^* \otimes e_k \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j \\
& = \sum_{k} \sum_{j} e_i \otimes e_k^* \otimes e_k \otimes e_j^* \otimes e_j.
\end{align}
Here $1$ is the identity map on $V$.

Therefore $\delta$ is a coaction.